# Детерминированный и недетерминированный алгоритм (формализация)

Tags: алгоритм, терминология, теория-автоматов

Столкнулся с тем, что качество определений википедии оставляет желать лучшего. Да, текста там много, но при этом формализация не является полной и точной. Остальная часть рунета пуста, в буквальном смысле. Все что есть, сотни сайтов копи-пасты с той же википедии. Поиск по книгам, посвященным программированию и алгоритмам (в частности) тоже не дал результатов. Определений либо вообще нет, либо приводятся отрывочно, либо качество перевода и работа редактора настолько запредельная, что сложно уловить смысл.

Решил формализовать различия между ними самостоятельно. Понял, что не смогу один с этим справиться. Кое-что у меня уже получилось, возможно с вашей помощью получится заполнить пробелы в определениях, обозначенные тильдами.

Если можете сформулировать лучше, дайте свои определения для ***детерминированного*** и ***недетерминированного алгоритма*** (*стохастический*, уже имеет максимально полное и при этом не большое, но понятное определение).

> К ***разветвляющимся*** алгоритмам можно отнести:

---

> - *Алгоритм*, поведение которого полностью зависит от входных данных, называют ***детерминированным*** |deterministic|. Каждый его шаг заранее предопределен. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     Таким образом, обработка одних и тех же входных данных всегда приводит к одинаковому результату.

---

> - *Алгоритм*, поведение которого невозможно предсказать (*от чего оно зависит*?), называют ***недетерминированным*** |nondeterministic|.
>     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     Таким образом, обработка одних и тех же входных данных может приводить как к одинаковым, так и к разным результатам.

---

> Иногда, решение задачи сводиться к использованию случайных величин.
>
> - *Алгоритм*, поведение которого, помимо входных данных, определяется значениями генератора случайных (псевдослучайных) чисел, называют ***стохастическим*** |randomized|

Неужели никто, кроме википедии не в состоянии дать определения этих понятий,
которые в принципе, являются фундаментом программирования? Может есть подходящие книги? В общем странно, столько людей получают высшее образование, неужели профессора не дают таких базовых определений своим студентам?

Comment: *Чем определяется поведение (НА) не понятно* - произвольными побочными эффектами, такими, как race condition или скорость прихода пакетов по сети, если не приравнивать это к ГСЧ.

Comment: @etki детерминированность и побочные эффекты - это явления разного порядка. Вы же их смешиваете. Если разберётесь в том, что такое "чистота функции" и чистая функция, все станет понятней.

Comment: Стохастический - частный случай недетерминированного. Ну, а недетерминированный - например, в котором нет случайных чисел в чистом виде, но есть какая-нибудь многопоточность, которую вы не можете предсказать. Не уверен, но, возможно, сюда можно отнести алгоритм, который, например, зависит от количества доступной памяти.

Comment: "Стохастический - частный случай недетерминированного?". Иногда кажется, что это действительно так. Ведь они очень похожи. Если используются **истинно** случайные числа, результат работы обоих невозможно будет предсказать. Однако к сожалению, ваше предположение ошибочно.

Comment: @Harry Вот что по этому поводу говорит Национальный Институт Стандартов США (NIST):  Nondeterministic algorithm - A conceptual algorithm with more than one allowed step at certain times and which always takes the right or best step. **It is not random, as in randomized algorithm**, or indeterminate. Rather it has the supercomputational characteristic of choosing the optimal behavior.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, что-то я вообще не могу представить "Nondeterministic algorithm". Случайные берем числа, псевдослучайные или функцию от текущего состояния компьютера, все это можно представить также как входные данные  для алгоритма. И для одинакового набора входных данных программа (на одной и той же машине (впрочем, тут уже речь опять о состоянии в качестве входных данных)) всегда пойдет одним и тем же путем.

Comment: `которые в принципе, являются фундаментом программирования` отнюдь не являются. Это уже исторические термины, как `феодализм` в истории - никому не интересные.

Comment: @avp а если не только компьютера, что например если внутри функции HTTP запрос, который ломится, например получить курсы биржи, а затем эти курсы используются дальше внутри функции для вычислений? Или например алгоритм, который с вебкамеры считывает видеопоток, и подрисовывает вам пиратскую шляпу? В общем любой алгоритм, который использует информацию о "внешнем" мире, это интересно как попадёт на такие термины

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр почему вы считаете эти термины устаревшими и феодальными? Скорее наоборот, это передовой край науки.  Задача о равенстве классов P и NP до сих пор не решена. Нейронные обучающиеся сети, которые сами принимают решения, начинают массово внедрять только сейчас. Недетерминированной вычислительной машины ещё не создано. Все персональные компьютеры на сегодняшний день являются детерминированными. А кроме того, любопытно посмотреть на лицо работодателя, когда на вопрос - дайте определения этих алгоритмов, вы скажете: "Мне это не интересно" ))

Comment: @Michael Не интересно то, что не способствует решению задачи. Учёным, может быть интересно. Тут же сообщество инженеров - практиков. Если начальник на собеседованиях такие вопросы спрашивает, это говорит только о его некомпетентности - и о том, что надо давать ноги с такой работы. Ещё в школе учат тому, что суть алгоритма в том что на одних и тех-же входящих данных будут одни и те-же выходящие, дальнейшего углубления не требуется - ибо всё за что платят деньги в IT сегодня основывается именно на этом принципе. То-же самое и является основой науки

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, биржевой курс, видеопоток и т.п. -- все это входные данные. Если в 2-х разных вызовах функции вычисления (как вы пишете) они будут *одинаковы*, то и результат ее работы будет одним и тем же. Разве не так? Если данные разные, то очевидно мы имеем дело со стохастическим алгоритмом в котором вместо равномерно (или каким-то другим, но определенным образом) распределенных случайных чисел используются случайные числа с неизвестным распределением. Т.е. я считаю, что вааш пример это *стохастический* алгоритм. Возможно именно ими и надо практически ограничить эту тему.

Comment: Всегда есть контекст, внутри которого определенность есть. Но если брать другой контекст, к примеру, обработка данных посредством многопоточности, то там при одинаковых входных данных результат может быть иным. И тут будет не важно на сколько изолирован алгоритм, будь он хоть начистейшей функцией, но в контексте где есть неопределенность он тоже в итоге станет неопределённым.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Такие виды алгоритмов были введены в обращение [в
1967 году Робертом Флойдом](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm#cite_note-1). Если обратиться к первоисточнику, то картина будет следующая:

Определение детерминированного алгоритма вы уже дали в вопросе.

Недетерминированный алгоритм отличается от детерминированного алгоритма не фактом использования случайных чисел, а наличием других переменных, влияющих на результат, кроме полученных из входных данных. Если вы возьмете какую-то функцию, реализующую недетерминированный алгоритм, то один раз для входного числа она вернёт один результат, а в другой раз для того же числа она *может* вернуть другой результат.

Таким критериям соответствуют функции, реализующие ГПСЧ. Вызывая функцию `rand()` вы получаете каждый раз другое число, даже если вы явно зададите исходное число для генератора случайных чисел вызовом `srand()`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    srand(42);
    std::cout << rand() << std::endl;
    std::cout << rand() << std::endl;
    std::cout << rand() << std::endl;
 
    std::cout << std::endl;
 
    srand(42);
    std::cout << rand() << std::endl;
    std::cout << rand() << std::endl;
    std::cout << rand() << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

[Выведет:](https://ideone.com/CV9b1d)

```
71876166
708592740
1483128881

71876166
708592740
1483128881
```

Как видите, поведение функции `rand()` предсказуемо и зависит от исходного внутреннего состояния. Вместе с тем, если вы не знаете исходного состояния, то поведение предсказать будет сложно, если вообще возможно.

Внутреннее состояние алгоритма - это не входные данные. Вы не обязательно можете на них влиять. Например, возьмём кошку. Если кошка сыта и здорова, то она будет рада ласке. Если кошка голодна или больна, то при тех же действиях с вашей стороны (входных данных) вы практически гарантировано будете поцарапаны. Таким образом можно сказать что поведение кошки определяется недетерминированным алгоритмом.

Алгоритмы, которые определяются случайными числами, являются подвидом недетерминированных. Их принято называть вероятностными алгоритмами (probabilistic algorithms). Например, к числу таких можно было бы отнести простую нейронную сеть в которой изначальные веса указываются случайными числами. При прочих равных для данного набора данных и данных исходных весов после обучения вы всегда получите те же самые конечные веса. Другим примером алгоритм, который одновременно недетерминированным и вероятностным, может быть сверточная нейронная сеть, которая содержит содержит [dropout-cлой](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#Dropout). Итоговые веса после обучения в такой сети могут случайно отличаться при тех же входных данных и исходных весах.

Comment: Сортировка массива чисел с выбором случайного элемента в качестве опорного является детерминированным или недетерминированным алгоритмом? Результат ведь всегда один и тот же.

Comment: @Qwertiy это будет стохастический алгоритм, но не всякий недетерминированный алгоритм будет стохастическим

Answer (score 2):

Дабы избежать введения лишних зависимостей (типа времени, ввода и прочего) и интроспекции в чёрный ящик алгоритма, предлагаю такие определения:

**Детерминированный**: алгоритм, который при наличии нескольких верных ответов, всегда выдаёт один и тот же.

**Недетерминированный**: алгоритм, который при наличии нескольких верных ответов, всегда выдаёт один из них.

Связано это с тем, что результат работы алгоритма обычно проверяется простым естественным вопросом, как то *Найденный путь имеет длину не больше 5?* или *Равно ли значение функции нулю в найденной точке?*. И независимо от типа алгоритма на одних и тех же данных ответ *верификации* должен быть одинаков.

Comment: У многих задач есть только один ответ. Сортировка массива чисел с выбором случайного элемента в качестве опорного является детерминированным или недетерминированным алгоритмом? Результат ведь всегда один и тот же.

Comment: @Qwertiy считается ли время, за которое алгоритм выдаёт ответ, результатом работы алгоритма? Если нет - то оба детерминированы. Если да - для псевдослучайного всегда будет одно и то же (т.к. выборка случайного элемента предопределена входными данными), а для истинно случайного разное.

Answer (score 1):

В функциональном программировании было введено понятие "чистая функция".
Это такая функция, которая при определенных аргументах возвращает один и тот же результат. Всегда. То есть она не обращается ни к каким внешним ресурсам: не делает запросы в БД, не получает числа из генератора случайных чисел, не получает ввод с консоли и даже не выводит никуда данные (это тоже обращение к внешнему ресурсу: если данные выводить, возможны какие-то ошибки ввода-вывода, и вместо ожидаемого результата может возникнуть, например, исключение)
Алгоритм вычисления этой функции есть **детерминированный алгоритм**.

Функции, не являющиеся чистыми называют функциями с побочными эффектами. В них находятся **недетерминированные алгоритмы**. Стохастические - это их подвид.

Например:

```
// эта функция детерминирована
public static int DeterministicAdd(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

// эта функция недетерминирована    
public static int NonDeterministicAdd(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b + int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Не любая функция, не являющаяся чистой, является недетерминированной. Например, функция может сохранять свой аргумент в глобальную переменную, но при этом возвращаемый результат будет зависеть только от входных параметров.